# Do I always check for whether OAuth refresh token was changed?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

I plan to store the refresh token in the database. However, I'm not sure if I have to always check to see if I need to update the refresh token in my database when user login through Google Oauth on my website.

Should I be concerned about whether the refresh token gets changed and need to update it in my database?

Is it a must to always check whether the refresh token gets change and update the user's record in my database accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

If the user re authenticates. You pop up the window asking for consent then you should save the refresh token then. If you ask them more then once then you should always store the most resent.

Technically you can have up to 25 of them that will work.

There is no real way to check if they have a newer refresh token then the one you have so I am not sure how you are checking if its changed.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not exactly clear about the part you mentioned up to 25 of them to work. Do you mean an account will only be given up to 25 possible refresh tokens on a site?

Comment: As for the checking of newer refresh token, well, what I did was I compared the one I stored on the database with the one that came in from google. If it one from google's API was null, I assume it is still the same (ie, user did not revoke and re-authenticate). Otherwise, I will update the refresh token in the db with the one from google's API. Does this actually make sense?